# Outputting the results of 2 SQL date ranges into one output

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, case, between

I've been trying to sort this for ages and am now probably overthinking it so hoping you can help me.

I have a sales transaction table.  In it, is a dated list of every transaction which I want to view by account code and put side by side, but to compare the account 2019 spend against their 2020 spend using date ranges

So far, I can only get either one or the other, never both.

I've looked at nested selects, union and more than I can recall but I'm not getting anywhere.

I've gotten closer, I think with this code:

```
SELECT inv_account, 
    (SELECT SUM(basevalue)) from salestrans WHERE inv_invoicedate BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2020-03-31'), 
    (SELECT SUM(basevalue)from salestrans WHERE inv_invoicedate BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2021-03-31') 
FROM salestrans
GROUP BY inv_account
```

This is giving me the total for every account, not individual accounts.  Now I need to filter it down by individual account which I assume goes somewhere in the SELECTs in brackets but aren't sure how to do this.

Comment: Post some sample data?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and date/time functions are quite vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT inv_account, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN inv_invoicedate BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2020-03-31' THEN basevalue ELSE 0 END) total1, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN inv_invoicedate BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2021-03-31' THEN basevalue ELSE 0 END) total2
FROM salestrans
GROUP BY inv_account
```

Comment: That is absolutely what I needed.  Thank you so much!